# HGE-OpenGL porting Gfx_SetTransform function

Tags: opengl, graphics, game-engine

First of all - I'm nub in graphics programming Smile.

I support game based on ported version of HGE which doesn't contain OpenGL version of **Gfx_SetTransform**.
I found several examples of HGE-Opengl porting, but any example has this function.

Code:

```
void CALL HGE_Impl::Gfx_SetTransform(float x, float y, float dx, float dy, float rot, float hscale, float vscale)
{
   D3DXMATRIX tmp;

   if(vscale==0.0f) D3DXMatrixIdentity(&matView);
   else
   {
      D3DXMatrixTranslation(&matView, -x, -y, 0.0f);
      D3DXMatrixScaling(&tmp, hscale, vscale, 1.0f);
      D3DXMatrixMultiply(&matView, &matView, &tmp);
      D3DXMatrixRotationZ(&tmp, -rot);
      D3DXMatrixMultiply(&matView, &matView, &tmp);
      D3DXMatrixTranslation(&tmp, x+dx, y+dy, 0.0f);
      D3DXMatrixMultiply(&matView, &matView, &tmp);
   }

   _render_batch();
   pD3DDevice->SetTransform(D3DTS_VIEW, &matView);
}
```

So, can anyone help in porting of **Gfx_SetTransform** or make a suggestion (maybe some simple example or OpenGL functions which I should looking for)?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With OpenGL up to version not including 3 you can replace it with the following:

```
void GL2_SetTransform(float x, float y, float dx, float dy, float rot, float hscale, float vscale)
{
   glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
   glLoadIdentity(); // we start off a identity matrix

   // Instead of testing for 0, you should test for some
   // threshold, to increase numerical stability
   if( fabs(vscale) >= 1e-7 ) {
      glTranslatef(-x, -y, 0.0f);
      glScalef(hscale, vscale, 1.0f);
      glRotatef(-rot, 0., 0., 1.);
      glTranslatef(x+dx, y+dy, 0.0f);
   }
}
```

OpenGL-3 deprecated the matrix manipulation functions, so the code looks almost identical to the DirectX version (I changed a few things to improve stability):

```
typedef float mat4x4[4][4];
// OpenGL uses column major mode, so the first
// index selects column, the second row - this is
// opposite to the usual C notation.

// The following functions must be implemented as well.
// But they're easy enough.

// function to set the matrix to identity
void mat4x4_identity(mat4x4 *M);

// those functions transform the matrix in-place,
// i.e. no temporaries needed.
void mat4x4_rotX(mat4x4 *M, float angle);
void mat4x4_rotY(mat4x4 *M, float angle);
void mat4x4_rotZ(mat4x4 *M, float angle);

void mat4x4_scale(mat4x4 *M, float x, float y, float z);

void mat4x4_translate(mat4x4 *M, float x, float y, float z);


void GL3_SetTransform(float x, float y, float dx, float dy, float rot, float hscale, float vscale)
{
   mat4x4 view;
   mat4x4_identity(view);

   if( fabs(vscale) >= 1e-8 ) {
      mat4x4_translate(view, -x, -y, 0.0f);
      mat4x4_scale(view, hscale, vscale, 1.0f);
      mat4x4_rotZ(view, -rot);
      mat4x4_translate(view, x+dx, y+dy, 0.0f);
   }

   _render_batch();
   // get_view_uniform_location returns the handle for the currently loaded
   // shader's modelview matrix' location. Application specific, so you've to
   // come up with that yourself.
   glUniformMatrix4fv(get_view_uniform_locaton(), 1, false, view);
}
```

I put up source code for the matrix manipulation functions up here:
http://pastebin.com/R0PHTW0M
They're not using exactly the same naming scheme, though.